# Place cell data from Sheets into Docs

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-docs

I'm trying to populate an invoice. I have a Google Spreadsheets that calculates hours per project, and I want to bring that into a Google Docs. Despite much searching, I have found no way to do this.

I thought `IMPORTRANGE` would work as a new equation, but no luck.

How do you enter a formula into a Google Docs?

Comment: That can only be achieved though the usage of Google Apps Script.

Comment: jezz, and here I thought Import-range was going to work, ha! Okay. I'll get this cracking. Thankyou Jacob!

Answer (score 6):

The following piece of code will create a Google Document and will insert a dynamic text, as a paragraph, into the newly created document. All is done from within a Google Spreadsheet.

### Code

```
// global
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

function onOpen() {
  var menu = [{name: "Create Document", functionName: "createDoc"}];
  ss.addMenu("Extra", menu);
}

function createDoc() {
  var sh = ss.getActiveSheet(), aRow = sh.getActiveCell().getRowIndex();
  var title = sh.getRange(aRow, 1).getValue(), docDate = new Date(); 
  var docTitle = title + "-" + docDate, doc = DocumentApp.create(docTitle);

  // create text in document
  var body = doc.getBody();
  body.appendParagraph("A paragraph " + docTitle); 

  // create app and panel
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle("Open Google Document")
    .setHeight(50).setWidth(400);
  var vPanel = app.createVerticalPanel()
    .add(app.createAnchor(docTitle, doc.getUrl()));

  // add to app
  app.add(vPanel);
  ss.show(app);  
}
```

### Add

The code in your Google Spreadsheet, under Tools>Script editor. Press the bug button to authenticate the code and all is set to go.

### Example

I've created an example file for you: [create Google Document with text](https://docs.google.com/a/familietuinstra.nl/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ApDwwZxW-IBcdEtFLW8wejVGVGtyNkRSYUFUME9tb3c&usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do something using the free add-on Reversible Formulas. I enables users to insert formulas anywhere in the document and compute them.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/formulas-for-google-docs/kgjbgmonlnhglokmfnpnklegakfknbeh

It supports all JavaScript formulas (including codes that use other Google Apis), plus for simple formulas, it enables users to modify the formula by changing the value.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of this add-on that I develop during my postdoctoral research